# How can I use jquery in a chrome extension content script when an older version is already on the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a chrome extension that fiddles around with the layout of a page. I want to use the latest version of jQuery to do this.

The page in question already includes version 1.4.4 of jQuery as part of one of their scripts.

If I include the newer version of jQuery, the page hangs. How can I include the newest version of jQuery so that it is only available to my content script, and doesn't affect scripts already on the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you inject your jquery as a content script it will be [sandboxed](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/content_scripts.html#execution-environment), you won't be having any conflicts no matter what a parent page is using.

Comment: _" For example, a content script could include JQuery v1 and the page could include JQuery v2, and they wouldn't conflict with each other."_

Answer (score 1):

You can essentially namespace differing jQuery versions by using its [No Conflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) and executing your code in a closure. For instance:

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jq162 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
    (function ($) {
        $(function () {
            // Your document ready code here
        });
    })(jq162);
</script>
```

Please note this declaration makes `jq162` available to the global scope so it can be reused elsewhere. If you'd prefer to scope the instance of jQuery locally, make it a `var`.

Comment: By passing the argument `true` to `noConflict()`, it restores both the original scope of the `$` and `jQuery` variables, to my understanding of the documentation.

Comment: That is to say the answer to your question is "no" when using the above call as indicated, in case I was unclear. xD (need caffeine...)

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my problem was something else, and content scripts are sandboxed, but this answer's useful anyway. You can actually shorten that code to this: `jQuery.noConflict(true)(function($) { /*document ready*/});`